# Value of integer in label (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, integer

I have a question, is it possible to make the value of a label in Qt set to an integer that changes during the program?
Kind regards

Comment: You mean something like `QLabel* l = new QLabel; l->setText(QString::number(10));`?

Comment: Kind of, it does change the value of a label but when the value of the integer changes (ex. 3 is 2 now) the value of the label doesn't change with it

Comment: You'll need to set up the right slots and signals to call `QLabel::setText()`. I don't think Qt provides the ability to tie the label of a `QLabel` object to the value of a variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel( this );

// ...

const QString text = label->text();

bool ok = true;
int value = text.toInt( &ok );
if ( ok )
{
    // The conversion was successful, you can use 'value'.
}
```

Or if you want to display an `int` just use:

```
int value = 7;
label->setText( QString::number( value ) );
```